# How to create a background service in MAUI?

Tags: maui

I have a `MAUI` application and I want to send a remind to the user every day at 8am (for example) to open the app and doing some exercises. I couldn't find a documentation about it.

I only found a recent answer on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1183356/net-maui-background-service) that refers to those links for Xamarin only for iOS and Android that:

- [Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services)
- [iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks#creating-background-safe-tasks)

Is it possible to create a background process for all the platforms? What about Windows and MacCatalyst?

Comment: You want to set alarms?

Comment: Yes and at the time, I want to do something like send a toast message to remind to do the exercises.

Comment: Any updates? Have you resolved your problem?

Comment: Not yet, I'm still looking around

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create a background process for all the platforms?

We need to understand that background services depend on which platform we use. So, we couldn't create a background process for all the platforms with just a public code.

Take Android for example:

We can add the following code on `MauiProgram`:

```
// Add dependecy injection to main page
   builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
 
#if ANDROID
   builder.Services.AddTransient<IServiceTest, DemoServices>();
#endif
```

And we can create our Interface for DI which provides us the methods to start and stop the foreground service:

```
   public interface IServiceTest
{
    void Start();
    void Stop();
}
```

On Android, add following code on `MainActivity.cs`:

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
   //set an activity on main application to get the reference on the service
   public static MainActivity ActivityCurrent { get; set; }
   public MainActivity()
   {
      ActivityCurrent = this;
   }
}
```

Finally, create our Android foreground service.

```
[Service]
public class DemoServices : Service, IServiceTest //we implement our service (IServiceTest) and use Android Native Service Class
{
   public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
   
   [return: GeneratedEnum]//we catch the actions intents to know the state of the foreground service
   public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
   {
      if (intent.Action == "START_SERVICE")
      {
         RegisterNotification();//Proceed to notify
      }
      else if (intent.Action == "STOP_SERVICE")
      {
         StopForeground(true);//Stop the service
         StopSelfResult(startId);
      }
      
      return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
   }
    
   //Start and Stop Intents, set the actions for the MainActivity to get the state of the foreground service
   //Setting one action to start and one action to stop the foreground service
   public void Start()
   {
      Intent startService = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, typeof(DemoServices));
      startService.SetAction("START_SERVICE");
      MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.StartService(startService);
   }
    
   public void Stop()
   {
      Intent stopIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, this.Class);
      stopIntent.SetAction("STOP_SERVICE");
      MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.StartService(stopIntent);
   }
    
   private void RegisterNotification()
   {
      NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("ServiceChannel", "ServiceDemo", NotificationImportance.Max);
      NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
      manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
      Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, "ServiceChannel")
         .SetContentTitle("Service Working")
         .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha)
         .SetOngoing(true)
         .Build();
    
      StartForeground(100, notification);
   }
}
```

**Note:**

We also need to add Android Permissions on `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: Thank you for this code. Do you have something similar for iOS, Windows and MacCatalyst? 

Comment: For iOS, you can check  [iOS Backgrounding Techniques](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/).